# TypeError: unsupported type annotation 15

Tags: python, discord.py

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported type annotation 15
  File "W:\Apps\CG_{Capital_Gateway}\main.py", line 756, in <module>
    @client.hybrid_command(description="{/}Timeout A User")
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: unsupported type annotation 15
```

Got this error after adding a new command:

```
@client.hybrid_command(description="{/}Timeout A User")
async def timeout(ctx, target: discord.Member, seconds: int(15), minutes: int(0), hours: int(0), days: int(0), reason=None):
  if ctx.author.id == target.id:
    Weirdo = discord.Embed(title=f"You Cannot Timeout Yourself, Weirdo!", color=000000)
    await ctx.send(embed=Weirdo)
    return
  if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.timeout_members:
    duration = datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds, minutes=minutes, hours= hours, days=days)
    await target.timeout_for(duration, reason=reason)
    STE = discord.Embed(title=f"{target} Has Been Timedout for: {duration} with Reason: {reason}.")
    await ctx.send(embed=STE)
  else:
    await ctx.send("You lack Authority!")
    return
```

I am expecting to be able to run my code again without being stopped because of this error. I tried adding self & discord.interactions. I also searched the www

Comment: `seconds: int(15)` What is the `(15)` supposed to mean here?  And the same with minutes, hours, days.

Comment: 15 means the number of seconds. I wanted to make sure it thought it was an integer. I may have done that wrong. I don't actually know python im trying to learn

Comment: If it's supposed to be exactly 15 and never change, why accept it as an argument at all?  Just use 15 as a hardcoded value...

Comment: Did you intend for `seconds` to **always** be 15?  Or just to use 15 as the **default** if no value was provided?

Comment: Default if no value was provided

Comment: Now, im getting: Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'HybridCommand' object has no attribute 'Context'
  File "W:\Apps\CG_{Capital_Gateway}\main.py", line 757, in <module>
    async def timeout(ctx:commands.Context, target: discord.Member, seconds: int=15, minutes: int=0, hours: int=0, days: int=0, reason:str=None):
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'HybridCommand' object has no attribute 'Context'

Comment: Nevermind I solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration was wrong.

```
@client.hybrid_command(description="{/}Timeout user")
async def timeout(ctx:commands.Context, target: discord.Member, seconds: int=15, minutes: int=0, hours: int=0, days: int=0, reason:str=None):
  if ctx.author.id == target.id:
    Weirdo = discord.Embed(title=f"You Cannot Timeout Yourself, Weirdo!", color=000000)
    await ctx.send(embed=Weirdo)
    return
  if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.timeout_members:
    duration = datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds, minutes=minutes, hours= hours, days=days)
    await target.timeout_for(duration, reason=reason)
    STE = discord.Embed(title=f"{target} Has Been Timedout for: {duration} with Reason: {reason}.")
    await ctx.send(embed=STE)
  else:
    await ctx.send("You lack Authority!")
    return
```

Only thing had to be changed was the `int variables declaration.`

Comment: If you want you can check if they changed from the original value, but since they are optional, this is not necessary.